# how to display a div only when a button is clicked

Tags: html, button, onclick

Hi i want to only display the div id placeholder1, placeholder2, etc once i click different buttons.  but i am not sure how to start on it. do help me, thank you :-) below are my codes for the different div ids.

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="demo-container">
                <div id="placeholder1" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="demo-container" style="height:150px;">
                <div id="overview1" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <p>Carbon Dioxide Reading</p>
            <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder2" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="demo-container" style="height:150px;">
            <div id="overview2" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <p>Gas Reading</p>
            <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder3" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="demo-container" style="height:150px;">
            <div id="overview3" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <p>Humidity Reading</p>
            <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder4" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="demo-container" style="height:150px;">
            <div id="overview4" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <p>Temperature Reading</p>
            <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder5" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="demo-container" style="height:150px;">
            <div id="overview5" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try anything using javascript or jquery?

Comment: nope i am not sure how to do even start the onclick function :/

Comment: You need JavaScript to handle an event like this. If you're not familiar with JavaScript, jQuery is your quickest bet to get where you want to go. It would simply be something like 
$("#button1").click(function(){
 $("#placeholder1").show();
});

Comment: Add _onclick="myFunctionName()"_ to the element you want to trigger the click, then define the codes for _myFunctionName()_ within your javascript codes. Try it and let us know what you come up with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a div when a button is clicked, you can add this to your CSS:

```
.demo-placeholder {
display: none;
}
```

Then, for example, this is your button:

```
<input type="button" id="but1" class="buttons" onclick="showDiv1()">Show Button 1
```

Then add this to your JavaScript:

```
function showDiv1(){
document.getElementById("placeholder1").style.display = 'block';
}
```

**NOTE**

When you want to do this for multiple buttons, make sure to NOT use the same funciton, but change the numbers to the div you want to show. If you need more help with this, just let me know and I'll update my answer.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: what should i place for the divname?

Comment: The id of the div is the name CSS recognizes. When you add the id/class  of the div in your CSS, it knows which div you want to apply it to, so that's all. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic JQuery code:

```
$("#ph1").click(function(){
    $("[id^='placeholder']").hide();
    $("#placeholder1").show();
});
$("#ph2").click(function(){
    $("[id^='placeholder']").hide();
    $("#placeholder2").show();
});
$("#ph3").click(function(){
    $("[id^='placeholder']").hide();
    $("#placeholder3").show();
});
$("#ph4").click(function(){
    $("[id^='placeholder']").hide();
    $("#placeholder4").show();
});
$("#ph5").click(function(){
    $("[id^='placeholder']").hide();
    $("#placeholder5").show();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9382bcu/)

I added buttons with ids `ph1`, `ph2` etc...
and clicking on the button performs the follow:
`$("[id^='placeholder']").hide();` hides all elements that have `placeholder` text in their ID

`$("#placeholder1").show();` shows the element with the defined ID (in this case *placeholder1*)